# Following and unfollowing events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've done Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails 5 tutorial and am now trying to apply the code to my own app.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Follow/Unfollow an event
- Display total count of users following this event
- Users can see all the events that they are following

The current error appears when I try to render the conferences that current user is following.

The error that I get is:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Users#show
No route matches {:action=>"followers", :controller=>"conferences", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The line that causes the problem is:

```
  <a href="<%= followers_conference_path(@conference) %>">
```

Now obviously their is something wrong in my routing and I assume the following problem states that conferences is missing a required id?

Does anyone know the solution to my problem? Which is getting allowing users to follow events and see what events they are following

**USER CONTROLLER SHOW**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @managments = @user.managments.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root   'static_pages#home'

  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  get    '/my_conference', to: 'my_conference#show'
  get    '/conferences', to: 'conferences#index'
  get    '/conferences_list', to: 'conferences#index_admin'

  get    '/my_employees', to: 'employees#index'

  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'

  put 'activate/:id(.:format)', :to => 'users#activate', :as => :activate_user
  put 'deactivate/:id(.:format)', :to => 'users#deactivate', :as => :deactivate_user

  put 'activate_employee/:id(.:format)', :to => 'employees#activate', :as => :activate_employee
  put 'deactivate_employee/:id(.:format)', :to => 'employees#deactivate', :as => :deactivate_employee

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following
    end
  end
  resources :conferences do
    member do
      get :followers
    end
  end
  resources :articles
  resources :users
  resources :employees
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :managments  
  resources :conferences  
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]


end
```

**CONFERENCES_CONTROLLER.RB**

```
class ConferencesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index

      @conferences = Conference.paginate(page: params[:page])

      if params[:search]
        @conferences = Conference.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
      else
        @conferences = Conference.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
      end
    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @conference = Conference.new
  end

  def create

    @conference = current_user.conferences.build(conference_params)
    if @conference.save
      flash[:success] = "conference created!"
      redirect_to conferences_path
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @conference.destroy
    flash[:success] = "conference deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @conference  = Conference.find(params[:id])
    @conferences = @conference.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end


  private

    def conference_params
      params.require(:conference).permit(:conference,:country , :month, :presence, :audience, :cost ,:picture)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def correct_user
      @conference = current_user.conferences.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @conference.nil?
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you post line that is causing the error? It's not the routes, that `_path` method probably needs an ID passed

Comment: @Ruslan Of course stupid of me not to add it. I've added it

Comment: Ahh, i see the issue. Check your `UsersController#show` to see if `@conference` is being set anywhere. If not try:   `<a href="<%= followers_conference_path(current_user.id) %>">`

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you for your response. It's not displayed in UsersController#show could you tell me (or maybe even explain) how I should write it in the UsersController#show? Thank you!

Comment: @Notorious_Creed where have you added this line `<a href="<%= followers_conference_path(@conference) %>">` i.e. in which view?

The problem I feel is if it is on some path like new, where conference is just initialized but not saved so it doesn't have an Id. Or it doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: @Ruslan you should post as an answer

Comment: @aks I've posted it on the users page `users/1`

Comment: @Notorious_Creed Can you post the `show` method in the users?

Comment: `  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @managments = @user.managments.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
  end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, i see the issue.

Check your `UsersController#show` to see if `@conference` is being set anywhere.

If not try: `<a href="<%= followers_conference_path(current_user.id) %>">`

Comment: I've added `@conference = Conference.find(params[:id])` to `UsersController#show` and now it's working. Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use the user id to get the @conference object, I'm sure. Instead, you are probably generating a list of conferences the user is following. In that case, you'd use something like this

```
<% @user.conferences.each do |conference| %>
  <a href="<%= followers_conference_path(conference) %>"><%= conference.name %></a>
<% end %>
```

And, in Rails, you would usually use the `link_to` helper, and maybe include a count to show how many followers the conference has.

```
<% @user.conferences.each do |conference| %>
  <%= link_to conference.name, followers_conference_path(conference) %>
  (<%= pluralize conference.users.count, 'follower' %>)
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will try this out today and get back to you!